# Inner select query and performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Consider the following query, will it causes multiple trips to db to execute the inner select statement?

```
Table1.Select(x=> new{
   x.T1_Name,
   x.T1_Id,
   T2 =x.Table2.Select(y=> new {
      y.T2_Name,
      y.T2_Value
   })
}).ToList();
```

My guess is it would not since it's still an `IQueryable` and the whole query would be run on DB and the final result would be passed to client.

In `LinqPad` the inner query triggers multiple call to server.

Comment: No substitute for testing. May be different for different versions of LINQ to SQL / EF or even different providers.

Comment: That's invalid code to begin with so what you ask doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @JeffMercado can you elaborate how's it invalid?

Comment: You're asking us to explain why that code would cause multiple calls to the database, but that snippet of code would not compile at all. Copy that into your editor and watch all the errors pop up.

Comment: I copied the exact code I executed in LinqPad

Comment: @ShyamalParikh - you may want to add a tag for the programming language of your code snippet (c# for example).

Comment: How is `Table1` actually defined? Is it a table in your data context? How does that relate to `x.Table2`? I have some theories based on your use of `ToList()` on what to expect, but it's just that, theories. You need to fully define your question.

Answer (score 0):

I bet `Table1` is a list that was obtained in a previous query that contains a reference to `Table2`. Since it is a list, the results of that initial query has been set. However it didn't materialize the contents of the `Table2` result so it will now in these queries.

It's probably like this:

```
var Table1 = context.Table1.ToList(); // materialize Table1
var query = Table1.Select(x=> new{
   x.T1_Name,
   x.T1_Id,
   T2 =x.Table2.Select(y=> new { // Table2 not materialized, so do it now
      y.T2_Name,
      y.T2_Value
   })
}).ToList();
```

Remove those `ToList()` calls until you actually need it. It's preventing the query provider from doing its job.